# Display image on click in HTML / Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, image, button, onclick

hey, how can I make an image visible when a user clicks a button?
Using Html / Javascript

Also, the button is submitting a form which is going to a different url, it just takes a while to load the other page, therfore I want a loading type button.

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, it's PHP and Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple to acheive this across all modern browsers using jQuery:

```
<input type="submit" value="Show Image" id="showButton" />
<img src="blank.gif" id="blankImage" alt="blank" style="display: none;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#showButton').click( function() {
    $('#blankImage').show();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the image's visible property to true?